# how to remove milky smell from mouth and clothes?

Tags: clothing, smell, home, after-wash

Sometimes my friends complained that I smelled like milk. I tried mouth wash with lemon juice and salt but can not get rid of it. Are there any hacks for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more recent feedback, or something you have heard from time to time? It would be important to not ignore smells that could indicate a change in health. Talk to a dermatologist or physician to be sure.

The next thing I would look at is identifying certain foods that may contribute to this. Such as milk, but could be others. We all process food differently and our smells and secretions may be an indication of items we process less efficiently than others.

Next in line would be the skin and the bacteria that causes the smell. You can use a mild solution of hydrogen peroxide http://www.using-hydrogen-peroxide.com/hydrogen-peroxide-bath.html . See also using for laundry. There are also neutralizers on the market both prescription and non prescription, but I would check with the dermatologist first.

Last defense would be to use a body powder to help absorb and neutralize the smell which may also help the absorption into clothes. For breath I would use gum, for the house I would use an ionizer based filtration (helps better with odor), and in the car keep some new car smell trees available (new car scent also does the best with odor I've found).

Answer (score 0):

I think, this issue can come under bad breath. Anyway, the same solutions can also be applied here too. Attaching them as follows:

- Hydrate: Drink enough water. When your mouth doesn't have enough moisture to produce saliva, odor-causing bacteria can develop.
- Brush and Floss: Daily tooth brushing along with flossing are the most important actions you can take to ward off bad breath.
- Clean Your Tongue: Cleaning your tongue can effectively decrease halitosis-causing compounds.
- Use a Mouthrinse occasionally: Use a mouth rinse after every meal which helps reduce plaque and gingivitis and freshens breath
- Use Traditional Remedies: Home treatments passed down over the years are a good complement to your daily dental care. Herbs such as fennel, for example, have long been used in some cultures as a breath sweetener.
- Controlled use of bubble gum: At certain times, some one can also use bubble gums if you have extreme bad breath. Bubble gums of not all type, certain products like these do exist in market for [these](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mint%20bubble%20gum&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=852&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCurfCjvHRAhXJnpQKHe_hB20Q_AUIBigB) purpose. As it is not good for health, i am not encouraging this solution.

Comment: Maneesh, I'm curious what effects bubble gum has on your health.

Comment: re: bubble gum - Dentists recommend certain sugar free gums can help prevent tooth decay, so I assume it would help clean the mouth. http://www.ada.org/en/science-research/ada-seal-of-acceptance/product-category-information/chewing-gum